# Plotting high exponent data came out a straight line in jupyter with matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I have a data ranging from E^-35 to E^-17 plotted against plt.arange(0,1,0.01,float)

But the result that came out was not as what I expected

It came out as a scatter plot at x=0

```
fig0 = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot( 111 )
ax0.scatter( data, np.arange(0,1,0.01, float) )
plt.show()
```

[image: test]

My data is

[8.1374114674802597e-34, 3.1029550981861939e-33, 1.1597885475591305e-32, 4.249093142425394e-32, 1.5259060563175121e-31, 5.3712263279542833e-31, 1.8532466296313074e-30, 6.2676840470669414e-30, 2.0777585717378257e-29, 6.7514519329613693e-29, 2.1503709667687085e-28, 6.7134182663760851e-28, 2.0544147967282703e-27, 6.1623544285318554e-27, 1.8118378266076862e-26, 5.2216298447246435e-26, 1.4750507130901448e-25, 4.0843404182592419e-25, 1.1085391173145788e-24, 2.9491320831520085e-24, 7.6904461440246843e-24, 1.9657258864483237e-23, 4.9250255625136312e-23, 1.2095062905130028e-22, 2.9115341220471074e-22, 6.8698894333261671e-22, 1.5888822776169327e-21, 3.6020339750412715e-21, 8.0042012411717219e-21, 1.7434211238444047e-20, 3.7222086900772078e-20, 7.7895656892566942e-20, 1.5978642487125893e-19, 3.2127773238718804e-19, 6.3319209199795436e-19, 1.2232196500900031e-18, 2.3162611675507162e-18, 4.2991709423185681e-18, 7.8216073741229478e-18, 1.3948304504692927e-17, 2.4381529062694997e-17, 4.1774818091868502e-17, 7.0158824965566103e-17, 1.1549525882654105e-16, 1.8636318176073254e-16, 2.9476111245571357e-16, 4.5697702677808896e-16, 6.9443669074066644e-16, 1.0343917791808785e-15, 1.5102594858792363e-15, 2.1613853049710207e-15, 3.0319841524935535e-15, 4.16903719647446e-15, 5.6189960042533021e-15, 7.423279057200236e-15, 9.6127347995666781e-15, 1.2201472498036293e-14, 1.5180694486447218e-14, 1.8513355693857711e-14, 2.2130578197031099e-14, 2.5930714678655535e-14, 2.978175748164367e-14, 3.3527430377313704e-14, 3.6996814006944967e-14, 4.0016812608403043e-14, 4.2426262158113436e-14, 4.4090107652324378e-14, 4.4911923712397478e-14, 4.4843165941867072e-14, 4.3887918667758544e-14, 4.2102493249632879e-14, 3.9589931901231432e-14, 3.6490163131389593e-14, 3.2967116699543334e-14, 2.9194445863162421e-14, 2.534157584536242e-14, 2.1561606171497332e-14, 1.7982195347686173e-14, 1.4700036856351123e-14, 1.1778995241752241e-14, 9.2515005595000464e-15, 7.1224633450482873e-15, 5.3748008438286255e-15, 3.9756545492025782e-15, 2.8824980048934251e-15, 2.048535527467194e-15, 1.427026688747923e-15, 9.7439444890073833e-16, 6.5215618448657109e-16, 4.2784114065927355e-16, 2.7512343183374094e-16, 1.7341502674112552e-16, 1.0714205813048751e-16, 6.4885454703296974e-17, 3.8516678681795513e-17, 2.2411164278722972e-17, 1.2781861811609836e-17, 7.1455872617985816e-18, 3.9155777030446838e-18, 2.1031385150348866e-18]

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib hasn't been able to choose a linear scale to match your data well. Since your x-coordinate data span a wide range of magnitudes, perhaps a log scale would suit you better:

```
fig0 = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot( 111 )
ax0.scatter( data, np.arange(0,1,0.01, float) )
ax0.set_xlim(np.min(data), np.max(data))
ax0.set_xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, that's weird considering it successfully plotted it on matlab. The log scale doesn't really show the point I want to make, I mean it kinda does but it looks much nicer on matlab.

Comment: You might have to post a picture of what you want the figure to look like if you want to get the same effect in matplotlib.

Comment: i figured out what's wrong, i was using the wrong function. should've done plt .plot instead of .scatter. rookie mistake. thanks anyway